# Regular expression split string on colon

Tags: java, regex

I have a string 
String l = "name: kumar age: 22 relationship: single "
it is comming from UI dynamically now i need to split the above string to

```
name: kumar
age: 22 
relationship: single
```

My code is :

```
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+( ?= ?[^\\s]*)?)");
    Matcher mt = ptn.matcher(l);
    while(mt.find())
    {
        String col_dat=mt.group(0);
        if(col_dat !=null && col_dat.length()>0)
        {
            System.out.println("\t"+col_dat );
        }
    }
```

Any Suggestions will appreciated Thank you

Comment: Semicolumn = colon?

Comment: Why is there an `=` in your pattern, when you're not expecting any `=` signs in your input?

Comment: @shmosel I was assuming that he meant "semicolon", but there aren't any semicolons in his input either.  I don't have a guess as to what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\S+\s*:\s*\S+
```

Or this:

```
\w+\s*:\s*\w+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/6

Regex:

`\S+` - 1 or more non space characters

`\s*` - 0 or more space characters

`\w+` - 0 or more `\w` i.e `[A-Za-z0-9_]` characters.

Comment: But if name is "petter John" then i am getting only petter

Comment: @kumar Then you can regex split on space with positive lookahead. `(?=\w+\s*:)`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/10

Comment: Hi 
(?=\w+\s*:)  this is not working...
Could u please help me to get rid of this..
Thank you for your support.

Comment: @kumar Try `string.split(" \\(?=\\w+\\s*:\\)")`. Please check other answers on SO on how to split a string with regex. I don't have exposure to java.